# How to only get first object of an array from API call and transform it and pass the object to the assembleMyModel function in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

How to only get first object of an array from API call and transform the first object of the array according to myModel and pass the object to the assembleMyModel function in RxJS?

API call returns more than one object in an array. I need the first object.
I am able to transform the data but I am transforming the whole array. I need to transform the first object and then pass the transformed object to assembleMyModel function.

API sample data:

```js
   data: [
    {
      "vehicleYear": 2016,
      "vehiclemake": "zzz",
      "vehicleeColor": "Red"
    },
    {
      "vehicleYear": 2017,
      "vehiclemake": "zzz",
      "vehicleeColor": "Blue"
    },
    {
      "vehicleYear": 2018,
      "vehiclemake": "zzz",
      "vehicleeColor": "Blue"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think away to achieve what you want could be the following

```
getData$(model: string): Observable<myModel> {
    return this.http
      .get(`${this.path/model=${model}`).pipe(
        map((resp) => resp.data[0] as Vehicle),
        map(firstVehicle => assembleMyModel(firstVehicle))
      )
}
```

[Here a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-4iuua9?file=index.ts) to see the code with http call simulated).

Answer (score 0):

Add `[0]` after first `map`

**Final output:**

```
getData$(model: string): Observable<myModel> {
    return this.http
        .get(`${this.path/model=${model}`)
        .pipe(
            map(({ data }: any) => {
                return data.map(item => {
                    return {
                        year: item.vehicleYear,
                        make: item.vehiclemake,
                        model: item.vehiclemodel,
                        equipmentType: item.vehicleequipmentType,
                        vinPrefix: item.vehiclevinPrefix
                    };
                })[0] as myModel;
            })
        );
}
```

Working demo at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gw1zpn?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: I do not think this solution can work. `map` does not return an `array`.

Comment: No. It will. See the new solution. @Picci

Comment: Now it works. Now the inner `map` is the Array method. If I remember right, in your original answer the `map` to which `[0]` was applied was the rxjs `map` operator, which is a different thing from the `map` method of Array.

Comment: Right you are. Thanks. :)